# Laravel 5.1 DBQuery Join

Tags: mysql, laravel, join, laravel-5.1

I have two tables:

```
products: id, name, manufacturer
myproducts:id, user_id, product_id
```

I know the user_id through my auth token.  With this user_id token, would like to get the product_id and id from myproducts and then query the products table to get the name and manufacturer where product_id in mymproducts matches id in the products table. The goal is provide an editable list to the user that he/she can edit in myproducts table.

So far I have only able to do

```
$productlist = DB:table('myproducts')->where('user_id', $userid)->get();
```

This returns all the products a user owns.  But I am having trouble joining the tables to return the product data for each product owned by the user.

Any suggestions?

Pseudo Code:

```
Select * from myproducts wheer user_id = $userid
```

for each product -> get product name and manufacturer where id is equal to product_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$all_products = \DB::table('myproducts')
                 ->leftjoin('products', 'products.id', '=','myproducts.id')
                 ->where('myproducts.user_id','=',\Auth::user()->id)
                 ->WhereNull('products.deleted_at')
                 ->get();
```

Comment: It worked with a slight tweak.  I wanted id from myproducts as well.  I ended up join a join instead of a leftjoin and called products in table and myproducts after join.   Also provided $user_id since I am using a different Auth mechanism than out of box Laravel Auth.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this using DB::table queries, but the best way to do this in Laravel is to use Eloquent relationships.

Create a [Model](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#defining-models) for both tables, then use the models to define relationships between your tables.

After you have done that, getting the product data for a product owned by a user is as simple as this:

```
$productData = User::find(1)->product;
```

I strongly suggest watching this tutorial on setting up Eloquent relationships, it explains it really well:

https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals

Comment: If I were just find the product this approach would have worked.  But I am looking to query multiple tables.  The many to many relationship would have most likely worked but it was going to be an overkill for what I am doing.   All I needed is a function in my restful api to do CRUD.  Thank you for your help.